# Jquery ajax parse through return html

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do I find an element named findThis in the ajax html response? I can't even find the first child (Error message: Object doesn't support property or method 'first')

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: www.someWebSite.com,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
            dataType: "text/html", 
            success: function (html) {

           var topHtml=  $(html).first(); 

            }
       });
```

I am using Jquery 1.8.2

Comment: Does `dataType: "html"` fix it?

Comment: maybe try `$(html)[0].firstChild` to access the DOM methods directly?

Comment: I tried that, didnt work :(

Comment: try changing your response to json

Comment: try this $(html + ' div:first-child')

Comment: What's the result of console.log(html)?

Comment: When I check the value of html in the f12 tools in ie, I see a string that has html inside it something like "<HTML  id="tel">...."

Comment: Is `www.someWebSite.com` your website?  Is is on the same domain as this JavaScript?  P.S. `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` is not needed, and `dataType: "text/html"` is incorrect, it should be `dataType: "html"`.

Comment: yes its in the same domain

Answer (score 7):

Strugled today with the exact same problem. After some frustrating hours I found out the following works in all occasions. Having a HTML file with sections like this :

```html
...
<h4>headline</h4>
<p id="id">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...</p>
...
```

I just wanted to look up the content of a `<p>` with a certain id and attach the content of that `p` to an attribute on an element.

```js
$.ajax({
    dataType: "html",
    url : 'path/to/html.html',
    success : function(html) {
        var div = $('<div>');
        div.html(html);
        var content = div.find('#id');
        $("#element").attr('attribute', content.html());
    }
});
```

Create a dummy element `<div>`, assign the HTML-response to that `div`; find the desired content from the `div`, extract it with `html()`.

jQuery seems to have a hard time parsing on-the-fly HTML. Especially if the markup is messed up. We must go through a dummy element and parse the content of that to get what we want.

All other solutions I have seen suggest parsing to HTML-nodes, does only return the empty element or does not return anything at all. The above seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This finds a div from the jquery site,

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://jquery.com',
            success: function (html) {

           var aDiv=  $(html).find('div').eq(0); 
console.log(aDiv.html());
            }
       });
```

Comment: That didnot work for me. What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @developer747 i tried this code from the console having visited jquery.com . The version they are using is 1.9.1 , you can see that if you execute jQuery().jquery at the console when at their site.