# Create variable from imported HTML's ID and children using jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am able to get the HTML from a webpage using this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    baseUrl = "http://www.somewebsite.com/";
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl,
        type: "get",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            // Create variable here
        }
    });
});
```

I want to create a variable that includes the text from the second anchor in the returned HTML from the AJAX request:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a></a>
            <a>I want to get the data from this anchor</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Quite frankly, I don't know where to start, as I am unfamiliar with jQuery. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you want the text between the anchor? Is that html the returned html from the ajax request?

Comment: @floor: Yes, that is the returned HTML from the ajax request. I want a variable that will have the text value: "I want to get the data from this anchor".

Comment: This other question answers your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717529/jquery-ajax-parse-through-return-html

Comment: Another way would also to treat it as a big string and use regex or some string manipulation to get the text you want. But the answer above is a lot quicker / easier. Likely if possible you would put a class or an id on the a tag you want to target. Then follow a similar structure to the answer in that question or you could target it with pseudo css classes such as nth child